# How can I unscrew my outdoor hose that is fused to the spigot?

Tags: faucet, corrosion

I don't know my own strength. It seems either my spigot or hose is stripped or they are fused together from corrosion. How can I unscrew the hose from the spigot?

Comment: Have you tried using a wrench to get more leverage?

Comment: Please explain why it seems like it's stripped. Is something spinning? Is it locked in place? What have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

Connectors left in place for long periods can get fairly well glued together by corrosion or mineral deposits. A pipe wrench should do the job. FYI pipe wrenches have angled jaws, to loosen you want the jaw facing left when you use it, that way it wedges on rather than slipping off. If you want to avoid marring the fitting try a bit of rubber between the wrench and the fitting. Most folks have a rubber washing up glove that will work.

Answer (score 2):

Hacksawing across the threads will at least give you a spot to place a screwdriver in the slot you created.  With a hammer, tap the screwdriver so that you are driving the fitting in a counter clockwise direction.  Little by little you will loosen the fitting so it can be removed.

Comment: This is the only method that worked in my case. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this like a stuck nut.  First, try more force.  A longer wrench will give you more leverage.  If that fails, try penetrating oil.  If that fails, try applying heat with a heat gun or blow torch.  Worst case, cut it off.

You won't know positively if it's stripped until you remove the hose.  If you are fairly certain that it is (or have another reason like the faucet leaks, is hard to use, etc.), you will need to replace the faucet anyways, so I wouldn't even bother trying to get the hose off and just replace the faucet.

Comment: Tapping gently with hammer around connection can fracture mineral deposits, and lower the amount of additional force required. Stressing the garden hose by bending in various directions near the connection may also achieve the same result.

Answer (score -1):

Cut the male part as close as possible to the spigot.  Then take a small chisel or screw driver and carefully tap the rest of the male part. It will come out in pieces, but it will come out.

Comment: The male half of this connection tends to be the spigot itself, I wouldn't recommend cutting that. How could you chisel out the male connection without damaging the female threads?